# New to Server 2019 - Is my domain computer communicating with my Domain Controller?

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

So I'm very new to Server 2019 and Active directory. No previous experience with any other server OS either.

I have set up 2 VM's on Hyper V. Server 2019 and a Windows 10 Pro. I have installed Active Directory on the Server2019 and enabled DNS.

I have managed to connect my Windows 10 Pro to the domain corp.summer.com. I see this in Advanced System Settings>Computer Name. (which is where I connected to the domain).

How can I tell if my computer is communicating with the domain controller? I know at some point it must have had connectivity because my first attempt to log in with my domain user account did not work because the machine couldn't find the domain(i joined the VM to the domain on the local admin user account), then i played around with my IP settings and i was able to then log into the domain user account for the first time

The IP I figured out by manually entering an IP on the same network the server is located on by figuring out the network separation using the Subnet Mask found in ipconfig, I made the default gateway the IP address of the Default switch created by Hyper V located in my Non Virtual Host machine in "Network and Internet">"Network Connections", and i set my DNS server to the IP listed on my Server2019 DNS. I did all this just trying different things and this seemed to enable me to log into my domain user for the first time. Also gpupdate /force works - when before playing with my IP gpupdate /force couldn't find the domain controller.

Also, there are other reasons i doubt my machine is communicating with the DC. I have given my domain user account membership of the Domain Admin group on Active Directory. It appears this has done nothing to elevate any privileges on the Win10 VM. This is why i am thinking the changes i make in Active Directory Users and Groups isn't moving to the Win10 VM.

A password GPO on AD did work however and i was able to modify the rules for password length and complexity.

I'm not sure if i should have added DNS to active directory when i set it up, I'm taking a community college course in Computer Admin, i havent even gotten to network+ material, I am just exploring.

Any tips or direction to point me in the right direction, or where to find articles/guides for first time setup of this type of network.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login to the Windows 10 workstation with a domain user account then the workstation is correctly joined to the domain and is able to communicate with the domain controller.

Make sure you can ping the domain controller and also the domain:

```
ping dc1.example.org
ping example.org
```

You should see the domain admins group is a member of the workstation administrators group and the domain users group a member of the workstation users group.

After you added the domain user to the domain admins group you would have needed to log off and back on to the workstation for that to take effect.